# Cannot resolve json import Intellij after adding dependency and library .jar

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

I cannot seem to resolve this issue after adding the json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar from an online source to the project dependencies, screenshots provided to show walkthrough of what I am doing. (and yes I have repeatedly tried "Invalidate caches and restart")

**The error:**
[image]

This is my Project Structure ("cmd + ;" or "File > Project Structure")

[image]
It doesn't seem to work on "Scope" set to Compile either. Note that I added the .jar file as a library too because I'm just really unsure as to why I can't get this to work. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

What do I seem to be doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jar you have downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/ doesn't contain the classes you need. This jar contains `net.sf.json` package which is a different implementation of JSON Java library.

You are trying to use `org.json.*` classes which are provided by another library. The library you want to use is this one: [JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java). At the bottom you can find the link to the Maven repository where you can get the jar file.

The latest version (at the moment of this reply) direct download link for the jar is here: [json-20160810.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20160810/json-20160810.jar).

Add it to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/working-with-module-dependencies.html) and your problem should resolve.

Next time you observe similar issue browse inside the library jar under External Libraries node of IntelliJ IDEA project view and see what classes it contains and under which packages. This way you would know if the issue is caused by the wrong jar you've added to the dependencies and which doesn't actually contain the classes you want to use.

Comment: I actually have changed it to compile that doesn't work either

Comment: In this case please update the question and share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide a link to the `jar` file you are using.

Comment: That resolved the problem. Thank you so much, work appreciated. I don't know a lot about dependencies - probably too used to IDE's that make it easier so thanks for the advice.