# What is the right way to add json-simple library on intellij?

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

It's been awhile since I programmed in java.

I'm trying to add json-simple on intellij but I can't figure out what is wrong ( almost moving back to eclipse)

The json-simple jar file is at the same directory of the project.

Here are some img's

[image]

[image]

[image]

thanks in advance..

Comment: would this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43686465/104891.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how you import it. First go to

```
File < Project Structure < Modules
```

Now, click on the `Dependencies` tab. It should look like this(Don't mind my libraries),

[image]

Click on the `+` icon, locate the Jar, and then click on `Ok`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply Chandler, but I've already did it. And it didn't work. Probably is something I'm doind wrong. Would you mind to try to add a json jar file on an example project just to check !?

Comment: works for me @EduardoHumberto see edit. Are you sure, you're doing it correctly ?

Comment: It should be something stupid that I'm doing.I'll do it again. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Chandler, you won't believe but the problem was the json jar file that I was using, thank you!!

Comment: @EduardoHumberto no worries :)